# A file exists in uwsgi and bottle, but a 404 error occurs

Tags: python, nginx, uwsgi, bottle

file organization

> ・/hoge/1/a/bottle.py ・/hoge/1/a/hoge.py ・/hoge/1/a/hoge.ini

---

/hoge/1/a.py Error displayed on the screen Display contents

```
   Error: 404 Not Found
    Sorry, the requested URL 'http://example.com/hoge/1/a.py' caused an error:

    Not found: '/hoge/1/a.py'
```

/hoge/1/a.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6 python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
from bottle import route, run, default_app

@route('/')
def index():
    return "Hello World!"

application = default_app()
```

/hoge/1/a.ini

```
[uwsgi]
uid = nginx
gid = nginx
socket = /var/run/uwsgi/app/%n.sock
chmod-socket = 777
chdir = /var/www/example.com/hoge/1
wsgi-file = /var/www/example.com/hoge/1/%n.py
file         = %n.py
processes = 4
threads = 2
```

a.ini log

```
announcing my loyalty to the Emperor...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because bottle only serves URLs which match one of the `@route`s that have been set up for it. In this case the only route that is set up is `/`, so only `http://example.com/` will work.